# Find the minimum number in an array with recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

```
int i = 0;
int min = x[i];
while ( i < n ){
    if ( x[i] < min ){
        min = x[i];
    }
    i++;
}
return min;
```

I've written the iterative form to find the min number of an array. But I'd like to write a function that with recursion. Please help!

Comment: Is the list sorted? If it is, recursion might make more sense, otherwise, recursion seems awkward here.

Comment: If the list was sorted, the first element would be the minimum and neither iteration nor recursion would make sense.

Comment: Well even if it was sorted, the last element could also be the minimum depending how it was sorted...

Comment: Let us not make any assumptions and consider the list as unsorted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because this sounds like homework, here's a hint: The minimum value in an array is either the first element, or the minimum number in the *rest* of the array, whichever is smaller.

Comment: Please note: Whether or not this actually *is* homework is not relevant. It's the kind of exercise that you will get immensely more value from if *you* discover the solution, than you will by copying the solution from somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum number of a single-element array is the one element in the array.

The minimum number of an array with size > 1 is the minimum of the first element and the minimum of the rest of the array.

(The minimum number of an empty array is not defined.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an optimal solution, because you may save the result of the recursive call in an int variable, but I wasn't allowed to in my exercise.

Anyway, this function searches the lowest value in an int array by using recursion.
As first it checks how many elements are in the array by checking if the size equals to 1 and then returns the first value as result. If the table is bigger than 1 (and technically also when lower) it compares the last value in the array with the recursive call with the rest of the array.

The recursion stops at the 0-index and then compares that value with the index 1. Then it compares the lowest value of index 0 and 1 with the value from index 3 and so on until it reaches last value.

```
int minimum(int array[], int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        return array[0];
    }
    else {
        return (array[size] < minimum(array, size - 1))
            ? array[size]
            : minimum(array, size - 1);
    }
}

int array[5] = {5, 99, 205, 1, 15};
int smallest = minimum(array, 4); // 4 = index of the last element
```

Rules in my exercise:

- Do not change the array
- Do not use any variable
- Use recursion

Comment: You show also write something to explain a bit what you did. Just to be understandable by a novice

Comment: @Federico I had no idea how to solve my exercise, even after looking at this page. I still had the page opened after I found the solution myself and decided to post it here. Anyway, I edited my post and added an explanation.

Comment: mine was just a suggestion (with an error :D show -> should. Damn smartphone auto-corrector) for a complete answer. For the future, it is appreciate if you comment your code because you can say more about it. Of course, this was a simple exercise so it was not really important, but it was a novice question, so I thing is nice to provide an answer for a novice. +1 for the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like homework, but your best bet is something like this:

```
int main(void) {
    int size = 2;
    int test[] = {0,1};
    int min = test[0];
    findMin(&min, test, size);
    printf("%d", min);
}

void findMin(int* min, int* test, int* length);

void findMin(int* min, int* test, int* length) {
    if (length >= 0) {
         if (*test < *min) {
            *min = test;
         }
         findMin(min, test++, (*length)--);
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically recursive but lacks gestalt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will return a pointer to the minimum value:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int *recursiveMin(int *x, int n) {
  if (x == NULL || n == 0)
      return NULL;
  if (n == 1)
      return x;
  int *t = recursiveMin(x + 1, n - 1);
  return *x < *t ? x : t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

general rule of recursion is to avoid "small steps" - so "first element compared to rest of the array" is very bad idea. try to process the array in halves, like this:

```
min( array ) {
   if size of array == 1 return array[0]
   else if size of array == 2 return array[0] < array[1] ? array[0] : array[1]
   else {
      firstmin = min( firsthalf) // stored to avoid double calls
      secondmin = min( secondhalf)
      firstmin < second_min ? firstmin : secondmin
   }
 }
```

for further optimization:
- avoid array copies - consider using quicksort-like signature (array, from, to)
- avoid recursive calls for sizes < 2

Comment: Of 10 answers, this is the only 1 that begins to perform recursion intelligently.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this with recursion? A general rule with recursion is don't use recursion if you can do it inside a simple linear loop.

Comment: Presumably because the assignment says to do it with recursion.

Comment: Meh. I like recursion. Basically, I apply the inverse of your rule (provided the compiler has tail recursion optimization).

Comment: Using tail recursion it would seem like there is no difference between a straight loop and recursion, assuming a semi-decent compiler.  It just depends what is more clear code-wise.

Comment: @Myles: exactly. And for that reason I often (not always) prefer recursion. For many things, recursion fits the natural expression of a mathematical concept quite literally, while iteration requires refactoring. I acknowledge that many people have a problem with recursion so I try to avoid it in an “unnatural habitat”. But the OP’s problem is actually extremely well-suited for recursion (it’s just a simple reduction using `min` as the operation).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  int recursive_min(list<int> arr) {
    return recursive_min(arr);
  }
```

Although this doesn't work in imperative languages.

A more serious answer would be, in pseudocode:

```
func recursive_min( list l ) {
 head = l[1]
 tail = l[2<->end]
 if l.length==1 return head else return min(head,recursive_min(tail))
}
```

Although that doesn't work if l is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int = 20;

int getmin (int v[], int n);

main ()
{
    int v[N];
    int i,n,min;

    printf("\n\tType number of elements:\t");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nv[%d]:\t",i);
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);             
    }

    min = getmin (v,n);

    printf("\n\n\tMinimume value is %d.",min); 
}

int getmin (int v[],int n)
{
    if (n>0)
    {
        if ( v[n-2] > v[n-1] )
        {
            v[n-2]=v[n-1];               
        }
        getmin (v,n-1);
    }

    return v[n-2];       
}
```

Comment: i've seen an exercise like thin in the exam of c, and i tried to solve it this way. 

I know i'm 1 year late for this discussion but maybe i might helpful for hereafter visitors.

Answer (score 0):

```c
int findMin(int a[], int len) {
//  normal version
//  if (len==1) return a[0];
//  return (a[len-1] < findMin(a,len-1))? a[len-1] : findMin(a,len-1);
//  memoization version, sort of?

    int rightside;
    if (len==1) return a[0];

    rightside = findMin(a,len-1);

    return (a[len-1] < rightside)? a[len-1] : rightside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int min(int [], int);
void mostrar(int [], int);

int main() {
    int f[] = {4, 9, 0, -1, 5, 8, -3, 6, -4, 0};
    int t = sizeof(f)/sizeof(int);
    cout << "\nEl valor m\xa1nimo para los valores:\n";
    mostrar(f, t);
    cout << "\nes: " << min(f, t);
    system("pause>nul");
}

int min(int x[], int p) {
    if (p == 1)
        return x[0];
    int aux = min(x+1, p-1);
    return x[0] < aux ? x[0] : aux;
}

void mostrar(int v[], int k) {
    if (k > 1)
        mostrar(v, k-1);
    cout << v[k-1] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int arrayMinValue(int[] array){
    if(array.length == 1)
        return array[0];
    else
    {
        int valor = array[array.length-1];
        int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length-1);
        Integer mun = arrayMinValue(newArray);
        return mun <= valor? mun : valor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a pseudo code**

```
ALGORITHM Unknown (A[0,...,n-1] )
if n=1 then
return A[0]
else
temp<- Unknown (A[0,...,n-2] )
if temp<= A[n-1] then
return temp
else return A[n-1]
```