# Can someone explain this code that recursively finds the minimum element in an array in C?

Tags: recursion

I don't quite understand this piece of code. So if for example `n = 5` and we have:

```
array[5] = {13, 27, 78, 42, 69}
```

Would someone explain please?

All I understand is if `n = 1`, that is the lowest. 
But when `n = 5`, we would get the 4th index and compare it to the 4th index and check which is the smallest and return the smallest, then take the 4th index and compare it to the 3rd index and check which one is the smallest and return the smallest? I am confused.

```
int min(int a, int b)
{
  return (a < b) ? a: b;
}

// Recursively find the minimum element in an array, n is the length of the
// array, which you assume is at least 1.
int find_min(int *array, int n)
{ 
   if(n == 1)
       return array[0];
    return min(array[n - 1], find_min(array, n - 1));
}
```

Comment: It's a recursive call, the find_min recurse call doesn't return until you've reached the bottom of the array. Write out the call trace, and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the minimum number in an array with recursion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735550/find-the-minimum-number-in-an-array-with-recursion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your array:

```
1. initial call: find_min(array, 5)
      n!=1, therefore if() doesn't trigger
2.    return(min(array[4], find_min(array, 4)))
          n!=1, therefore if doesn't trigger
3.        return(min(array[3], find_min(array,3)))
             n!=1, therefore if doesn't trigger
4.           return(min(array[2], find_min(array,2)))
                  n!=1, threfore if() doesn't trigger
5.                return(min(array[1], find_min(array,1)))
                        n==1, so return array[0]
4.                return(min(array[1], array[0]))
                  return(min(13, 27)
                  return(13)
 3.          return(min(array[2], 13))
     etc...
```

Comment: Why do you have find_min(n, 4), isn't it supposed to be find_min(array, 4)? Just wondering.

Comment: yeah, typo. first arg doesn't really matter, since it's constant through the call stack anyways. it's the `n` arg that counts.

Comment: So the 4th index, gets compared to index 4,3,2,1,0 and chooses the minimum? Then the 3rd index, gets compared to index, 3,2,1,0 and chooses the minimum? And so on?

Comment: no. there's still only 5 comparisons, since there's only 5 array elements. the call recurses down until it reaches the end of the array, then begins comparing those values on the way back up.

Comment: Okay so once it begins comparing those elements on the way up, it looks array[0], which only has 1 element, then it looks at array[1] which has 2 elements and finds their min? Then it looks at array[2], which has 3 elements and finds their min? Sorry I am just really trying to grasp this.

Comment: NO. `array[0]` returns the single value stored at that location in the array. `array[3]` also looks at the SINGLE value stored in location #3. the array index has NOTHING to do with how few/many values you want. it's a SINGLE element access.

Comment: Okay sorry again, I get how the call recurses down until it reaches a[0], but I don't get how it works on the way up.

Comment: anywhere you see a find_min() call, you just replace it with the value that was computed by that exact call, exactly as I did it in the `4.` line there.

Comment: Okay I see! I got it. Thank you! You were very helpful, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Run through the code using the example you gave.

On the first run through find_min(), it will return the minimum of the last element in the array (69) and the minimum of the rest of the array. To calculate the minimum of the rest of the array, it calls itself, i.e. it is recursive. This 2nd-level call will compare the number 42 (the new "last" element) with the minimum from the rest of the array, and so on. The final call to find_min() will have n=1 with the array "{13}", so it will return 13. The layer that called it will compare 13 with 27 and find that 13 is less so it will return it, and so on back up the chain.

Note: I assume the backward quotes in your code are not supposed to be there.

Comment: So 69 will compare itself with 42, 13, 27, and 13? Then it 42 will compare will compare itself with 13, 27, and 13?

Comment: Backward quotes, where?

Answer (score 0):

The solution uses recursion to compute the minimum for the smallest possible comparison set and comparing that result with the next bigger set of numbers. Each recursive call returns a result that is compared against the next element in a backward manner until the minimum value bubbles up to the top. Recursion appears to be tricky at first, but can be quite effective once you get familiar with it.