# C++ Recursion: Return the smallest even digit of a number

Tags: c++, recursion

Write a recursive C ++ function that returns the smallest even digit of a natural number transmitted as a parameter.
If the number does not contain any even digit, it will return -1.

Easy to do without recursion:

```
int cifminpar(int x)
{
    int mi = 9;
   while(x)
   {
       if(x % 10 % 2 == 0)
        mi = min(mi , x%10 );
       x /= 10;

   }
   if(mi == 9)
        return -1;
   else return mi;

}
```

How do I do that with recursion ?

Comment: What did you try? Where did it fail?

Comment: You mean digits?

Comment: Why is recursion even necessary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735557/1766544 (same thing, slight variation to find the digits)

Comment: One thought about Recursion that you should keep in mind: Put down the complex problem into smaller problems of the same kind.

Comment: Yes , the smallest digit. I think the link here from @KennyOstrom is good for what I am looking for! Thank you, sorry for double post , I am new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like the following?

```
int cifminpar(const int x)
{
    if(!x)
        return 11;
    //recursive call
    int minrest=cifminpar(x/10); //min even in the rest of the digits
    if(x % 10 % 2 == 0)
        return min(minrest , x%10 );
    return minrest;
}
```

It returns `11` if no even digits are found and work as follows and assumes that the initial number is not `0`. 
You can easily fix modify it  to return `-1` on failure and for `0` as input.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: The smallest even digit is either "the first one" or "the smallest one in the number without the first one".

You can recursively compare "current digit" and "the smallest digit after it":

```
  int cifminpar(int x)
  {
      int ret = cifminpar_recur(x, 10);
      if (ret == 10)
          return -1;
      return ret;
  }

  int cifminpar_recur(int x, int mi)
  {
      if (x == 0)
          return mi;
      if (x % 2 == 1)
          mi = min(mi, x % 10);
      return cifminpar_recur(x / 10, mi);
  }
```

And we can even drop the extra variable.

```
  int cifminpar(int x)
  {
      int ret = cifminpar_recur_optimised(x);
      if (ret == 10)
          return -1;
      return ret;
  }

  int cifminpar_recur_optimised(int x)
  {
      if (x == 0)
          return 10;
      if (x % 2 == 1)
          return min(x % 10, cifminpar_recur_optimised(x / 10));
      return cifminpar_recur_optimised(x / 10);
  }
```